# IccLockSettings call using Nougat Android 7 throws ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, activitynotfoundexception

In order to open SIM PIN settings, I am using this code up to Android M. 7.0 SDK 24, Sim is inside the tray. ^^

```
Intent  intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.IccLockSettings"); 
intent.setAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
intent.setComponent(cn);
startActivity(intent);
```

On Android N, I am getting à  android.content.ActivityNotFoundException

Any Clue ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `"com.android.settings.IccLockSettings"` try `"$IccLockSettingsActivity"`

If you use adb, don't forget to escape the `$` wth a `\`:

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings\$IccLockSettingsActivity
```